# Verilog random function with toggling

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How to generate verilog testvector using random function but with only 50% bits toggling
Ex: Address[7:0] value varying from 0 to 255 --> address to be generated something like 01010101, 00001111,11110000,10101010 etc

Answer (score 2):

You can constrain the number of changed bits by counting the number of bits set when you xor the random value with its previous value

```
 class req;
     rand bit[7:0] Address;
     constraint toggle_bits {$countones(Address ^ const'(Address)) == 4; }
 endclass
```

Complete example you can try [here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Qsib).